# edit magento navigation without coding

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, zend-framework, content-management-system

I just recently started working with a Magento site, and so far I'm really not liking it. I need to remove a couple links from the main navigation, but I can't seem to find the option for it. I've googled it numerous times, and all I see are examples for coding the navigation. My question is, can you edit the site navigation like you can with say wordpress? Seeing how it's a cms I'd imagine the user should be able to make changes to the navigation using some type of interface, and without having to pull the files from the server and edit them.

Also just out of curiosity, for anyone experienced with Magento would you say it's a good choice for a cms? I've heard of it before, but haven't seen many sites that use it.

Answer (score 1):

No!, so you have three options here.

1. Learn how to extend the navigation with the 100's of tutorials out there, it is really not that hard, assuming you have a theme you just have to edit `app/design/frontend/[theme]/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml`
2. Get an extension to do it for you.
3. Hire a developer to do it for you, we create a static block with installer for the html which make it slightly more user friendly to update in the future.

Stackoverflow is a bad place to ask questions like this, it is aimed at programmers and doing such a procedure is rudimentary stuff, I really hope you are a client trying to be cheap rather than someone who claims they can run this site.

Edit: The cms features are ok but you need to be able to code to set them all up so the end user can make the changes with WYSIWYG.

Comment: I’m not a client, I just got this magento site dumped on me. I've never had to work with Magento before, and don't want to play around with files on a live site. I was hoping there was an easy interface like wordpress so I would't have to worry about coding, or installing more plugins/extensions. I’ll just set up a test site on my localhost and play around with that. Thanks any way.

Comment: @HarryManback ok sorry for being condescending, magento is tricky and has a fairly steep learning curve, I feel bad for you having it dumped on you.

Comment: Sorry, But magento contains a huge number of features and implemented in great way and have lots of resources/documentation available on net. Please go through. I am sure you will also like this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure once I start working with Magento it'll begin to grow on me. The more tools the better... I'll set up a test site tonight and start going through the documentation. Thanks for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 1):

```
If you don't want to code for navigation then you can do below things
1) Create category and  then Display Settings=>Display Mode=>static block only and  Display Settings=>CMS Block=>static block name. In static block u can include in page url or custom page
2)You need to hire developer
```

Comment: I am a developer, just never worked with magento. This site has already been built, and has been live for a while now. Just trying to figure out how everything is put together. Thanks though.

Comment: OK, then you can refer http://alanstorm.com/category/magento for reference as Alan has given well documented data for developers

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Magento and have an integrated WordPress blog, it's possible to design a completely custom menu in the WordPress Admin using the menu builder. You have complete control over what menu items you want and the hierarchy of each item.

To get this to work, you need to integrate your WordPress blog using [WordPress Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration.html)  in full integration mode. Your Magento template also has to be using the default Topmenu block.

Comment: I may check that out. Thanks!